# k6 error when trying to send data to InfluxDB in the Cluster

Tags: performance-testing, influxdb, k6, xk6-browser

I sh file that executes a performance test in the Cluster k8s but when I execute the Pod appears a message: `level=error msg="Couldn't write stats" error="Action: Deny. Reason: No rule matched. Proceeding with default action." output=InfluxDBv1`

SH file:

```
apt install gpg -y
gpg -k
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/xk6-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C5AD17C747E3415A3642D57D77C6C491D6AC1D69
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/xk6-archive-keyring.gpg] https://dl.xk6.io/deb stable main" |  tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xk6.list
apt-get update
apt-get install xk6
k6 run --out influxdb=http://influxdb-k6.monitor.svc.cluster.local ./non-functional-testing/createOrganization.js
```

I received a response from someone on devoPs teams and he told me this error occurs when k6 is invoked as this is InfluxDB2, which according to the documentation k6 is incompatible with.

So, I have try to add this to the sh file:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt search golang-go
sudo apt search gccgo-go
sudo apt install golang-go
go install go.k6.io/xk6/cmd/xk6@latest

# Clone the xk6-disruptor code
git clone https://github.com/grafana/xk6-disruptor.git
cd xk6-disruptor

# Build the custom binary 
xk6 build --output xk6-disruptor --with github.com/grafana/xk6-disruptor=.

k6 run --out influxdb=http://influxdb-k6.monitor.svc.cluster.local ./non-functional-testing/createOrganization.js
```

as mentioned in the k6 documentation but then I get a response in the logs that SUdo is not recognized.
Does someone have a way to install xk6 in the sh file using linux?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? Your original file didn't use sudo when installing packages with `apt`, so why do you need it now? From the original script, it looks like that your container is running as `root` already.

Comment: I am using sudo because I am searching for a way to install xk6 in Linux, but I am not sure of how I can change apt for xk6

Comment: But your original script is already calling `apt install gpg -y` without sudo, so I assume your script is already running as `root`, is it not?

Comment: Yes, it is running as root.

Comment: Then why do you need `sudo`? Correct, you don't

Answer (score 0):

Your container is already running as root, there's no need to call sudo:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
...
```